# How to bind Dropdownlist using Datatable In Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For each DataTable, I'd like to create a table row and a drop down list for it.
My code here,

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
....
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor();
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What data should display the dropdown?

Comment: Two columns inside the DataTable.First Column value want to bind the dropdown.

Comment: you only need one foreach statement

Comment: No need the inside of loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @{
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row["associatename"].ToString(), Value = row["associateid"].ToString() });
        }
    }
    @Html.DropDownList("test", li)
```